# Como criar um TreeMap para armazenar palavras e as linhas onde aparecem?

Tags: java

Preciso iterar em um texto e pegar cada palavra dele, armazenar em uma estrutura (como `TreeMap`) e junto a cada palavra as linhas em que elas aparecem, para gerar um índice remissivo.

Minha grande duvida tem sido em como estruturar isso, pois usando `TreeMap` eu consigo colocar a palavra, mas apenas um `Integer` para cada palavra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um:

```
TreeMap<String, List<Integer>> mapeamento = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Assim você terá para cada palavra (String) uma lista de linhas em que ela ocorre. Essa lista suporta mais de uma ocorrência por linha e pode ser ordenada através de `Collections.sort()` se a inserção de linhas na lista já não for ordenada.